# SharePoint Structure Advice

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm just looking for some advice on the best way to structure documents in `SharePoint 2010` for a client. Basically they have about 10 `Business Units`, then potentially tens of thousands of `Clients` and for each Client they should have from 1 to hundreds of `Projects`.

What I'm thinking of doing is create a site per Business Unit, and then just have one Document Library containing a Folder per Client, and then a Sub-Folder per Project, and then in the Project folder have a number of standard folders to contain the different types of project documents. I will create code to automatically create this structure as Projects are added to their line of business app.

I appreciate this will results in quite large document libraries but they will have a decent structured in them with no particular folder having thousands of files in them.

The other option is to create a document library per client, but I think that's going to get very clumsy to navigate?

The one other thing I need to bear in mind is that in some point they might want to allow certain clients logon rights to certain folders inside their own client folder. This may be easier with Libraries but I think I can write code to automatically manage permissions that is no harder for folders than for libraries.

Thank you for your input!!

Comment: what is the user base? how many servers you have( i am looking for WFE) and also what services application required?

Comment: It's SharePoint 2010 Foundation, one WFE server and the SQL Server is a separate server, less than 100 users, at this point in time I only see them using Search and a couple Timer jobs, can't think of anything else at this stage

Comment: if they have only documents for project...then your approach will be fine....Site collection(for each Business Unit)-->Document Library(for each Client) --> Folder for each project....also recommend you, create security groups for managing the permission.

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually prefer to have one Document Library per site and then a folder per Client, that's my main concern - do you foresee problems with that?  Thank you!

Comment: the only problem is lenght of url, if you nested more folders and url( i guess more than 256 characters, not sure) will cause the issue. other than that no problem....always use short name..

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to place your comments in an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if they have only documents for project...then your approach will be fine....Site collection(for each Business Unit)-->Document Library(for each Client) --> Folder for each project....also recommend you, create security groups for managing the permission.

the only problem is length of url, if you nested more folders and url( i guess more than 256 characters, not sure) will cause the issue. other than that no problem....always use short name.